# Break throwing error when being included from a different file

Tags: php, include, break

I ran into some trouble while trying to use break on another file which is included in the first file under a while loop, and ran into an error. I'm wondering, is there a way around this, other than the apparent answer: which is to include the break under the first file. So, is there a way to include the break in the second file, somehow? Thanks.

**test1.php**

```
$count = 10;
while ($count > 0) {
$count--;
include("test2.php");
}
```

**test2.php**

```
echo $count."<br>";
if ($count == 5) {
break;
}
```

**Result:**

```
9
8
7
6
5
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in websiteName on line 5
```

Comment: You can't break in an included file, but you could setup a `return` in the include and use that to `break` in the outer file http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php  I get the feeling there's more to your real code than your example lets on so your situation may be more complicated.

Comment: if i recall  `return` will work

Comment: The linked duplicate is a bit different from the intent here, I think. `return` alone functions like a break to halt execution of the include, but the desire here is to use the include to break the loop in the including file. A `return` could be used to accomplish that, but it isn't as simple as a keyword replacement like the duplicate sort of implies.

Comment: @Dagon You mean use 'return' instead of 'break'? I tried that, but nothing happened, except that it printed out numbers from 9 all the way to 0, instead of stopping at 5.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You mean use 'return' instead of 'break'? I tried that, but nothing happened, except that it printed out numbers from 9 all the way to 0, instead of stopping at 5.

Comment: ok.. whats the real usage here?

Comment: @frosty No, I mean to specifically return a value like `return 'BREAK ME';` from the include when your condition is met, and then check the return value from `include()` in the outer file. `$ret = include('test2.php'); if ($ret == 'BREAK ME') break;`

Comment: @Dagon Well, I'm including a lot of files, and I'm checking if statements before including those files. Each files have a different if statement. Not all of the files will be executed. The files are all under a while loop, and every file has a chance to break the while loop, so the rest of the files will not be included, to increase the execution time.

Comment: @Dagon Depending on the user input, only the first file will be included, or all the files will be included. However, since there are so many files, I have to put a break condition under every files, so I thought it would just increase the execution time, if I just include the break statement in the files themselves.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Er...forgive me if I'm wrong, but couldn't I just include the break statement itself in the first file then?

Comment: @frosty The break does then go in the first file, but if it is the inner file which must cause the breaking condition, then this is one way to handle it. Like I said before, I suspect your situation may be more complicated than the simple example code.